# Determining why kernel hangs on boot

Tags: linux-kernel, gentoo

hi :
     i was building kernel for my gentoo linux . when i start the kernel , i 
     got this message , and can't going on.

```
pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
non-volatile memory driver v1.3


i don't know how to solve this problem . and i need help . thanks .
```

Comment: There isn't really enough information here to help you. You're going to need to add more detail.

Comment: Voted to close; this question is not answerable as-is.

Comment: @sharth - exactly what sort of detail do you think should be added?

Comment: @Chris Stratton: He says that he gets two messages: [nvram](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37.2/drivers/char/nvram.c#L461) and [hotplug](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37.2/drivers/pci/hotplug/pci_hotplug_core.c#L550). These are both informational messages and do not actually describe a problem. It would be helpful if he described the problem that he wants to solve.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: I'm also not sure how you pulled the question "Kernel won't boot" from this post. Neither of these messages have anything to do with that however, as they don't report an error condition.

Comment: @sharth - these appear to be all he has to go on.  What more do you want him to post?  If you have specific suggestions for available information, that would help, please raise them.  My feeling is that these messages need to be used as a guide to investigative experiments, as I suggested below. He can't exactly post enough context for one of us to do those experiments.

Comment: @sharth - if you aren't sure where I deduced that question from, then what is your theory for why this post exists?  What does "when i start the kernel , i got this message , and can't going on." mean to you?

Comment: @Chris Stratton: If his problem is that his computer won't boot, then it's off topic for stack overflow.

Comment: @sharth - his problem is that his customized computer program will not start up, which is 100% on topic for stack overflow, at least if he is willing to approach it as a programmer would.  The fact that the program is a linux kernel does not change that.

Comment: An old off-topic questions, flagged.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to disable pci hotplug support in kernel (if I recall correctly is in main config menu / PCI support)? You probably don't need this.

Comment: i don't know if the "non-volatile memory driver v1.3" is  caused by "pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5"

Comment: grep the sources and find which files those strings are in.  Are they related? or unrelated components which happen to start up sequentially?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to have to disagree with those voting to close, because I think there really is a question here, and the question is "How to debug this?"

I'm going to propose two approaches:

1) Studious approach: Learn about mechanisms intended for handling boot problems.  See if you can increase the kernel debug message level.  Disable un-needed drivers as Quizzo suggested.

2) Cowboy approach: grep the kernel sources for strings seen in the final messages, and start shotgunning all possibly relevant bits of code with your own "still alive at" printk messages.  Once you know where it's hanging, figure out why and either remove that mechanism or fix it.

At an extreme there's also a tool for debugging the kernel - kgdb - which you could set up if you have a second machine available.

If you already have linux running on this box, see if there's a config.gz in /proc or in a boot folder which you can extract and compare to the configuration you are trying to compile.  It might not be a bad idea to first recompile and test exactly the same version and configuration as you have running, and then make desired changes one by one.

Also you might see if there's odd hardware in your system you could temporarily remove.  For example, an older PC I have has a bios that hangs during drive enumeration if I have a large USB external drive plugged in during boot.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem by enable all pci hotplug flag in kernel config file.
thinks all.